# Programmatically Navigate w/ HashRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I was originally using `hashHistory` from `react-router` and programmatically navigating my React app using `this.props.history.push()`. But with the move to using `HashRouter` from the `react-router-dom` package, `this.props.history.push()` now throws a `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` error.

How do I programmatically navigate using `HashRouter` now?

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          <Route path="/landing" component={Landing} />
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </Provider>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Render func of **App.js**

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...
      <div>
        <Collapse isOpened={this.state.activeForm === 1}>
          <SignUpForm />
        </Collapse>
        <Collapse isOpened={this.state.activeForm === 2}>
          <SignInForm />
        </Collapse>
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Function in **SignUpForm.js** that's calling `.push()`

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  ...
  this.props.history.push('/landing');
  ...
}
```

Comment: `history.push()` is still there in react-router v4. But it might not available depending on where you use it and how you have configured your routes. If you can share some more code which explains those, we might be able to give you a solid answer.

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara, just added related code.

Comment: where do you try to use `this.props.history.push()`, inside Landing component?

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara I'm using `.push()` inside a different container `SignUpForm.js` which is inside `App`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your component is rendered from a Route (like App and Landing), then you will have access to all router related props (`match`, `history`, `location`). However, since SignUpForm isn't rendered with a Route, you won't have access to those props by default.

But we can use [`withRoute` higher-order component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) to explicitly get those props. We just need to wrap the component with this HoC before exporting it as follows.

```
export default withRouter(SignUpForm);
```

Now it will work as expected since SignUpForm gets `history` prop.

Comment: If I'm already implementing redux, how would I wrap the component?

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignUpForm);`

Comment: @Mike Wrap the connected component `withRouter(connect(...)(MyComponent))`

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what my issue is. My **index.js** is set up as such (below) with **App.js** as one of the routes, *not* **SignUpForm.js**, which is a container being rendered in **App.js**. This means that **SignUpForm.js** has no notion of the **history prop** within **App.js**.

By passing **App.js**'s history prop to **SignUpForm.js** as a prop, I was able to call `this.props.history.push()` within **SignUpForm.js** to get my desired action.

Comment: This will work for immediate child components. But sometimes you will have to pass `history` many levels down. Then using `withRouter` is easy and clean.